# Eloquent multiple select in the same query

Tags: php, eloquent

Doing my firsts steps in eloquent, I'm trying to achieve a query that retrieve some data and count some conditions at the same time.

This raw SQL sentence works as expected

```
SELECT *
FROM photos, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos where type = 1 and published =1 group by type) as qA, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM photos where type = 2 and published =1 group by type) as qP
where product_id = 7 
and published = 1
```

But using Photo model I can't get the same results

```
Photo::select(*,
Photo::raw('count(*) where type = 1 and published =1 group by type as qA),
Photo::raw('count(*) where type = 2 and published =1 group by type as qP))
->where ('product_id',7)
->where('published', 1)
->get()
```

Stripping out "raw" sentences, this query works, but I need to count those "type" ocurrences.

Thanks in advance for any guide over it.

Comment: Try writing ->toSql() instead of ->get() and you'll print out what's the sql equivalent. You can then make changes to whatever you need (my resolution whenever I gotta rework queries)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to get all in one query? Does it make sense for your application? I mean, I guess those types count are not really information about the record(s?) you are fetching (product_id = 7), rather they are general information about the state of the table as a whole.

If this makes sense, you could try

```
$photo = Photo::where ('product_id',7)
    ->where('published', 1)
    ->get();

$types_count = Photo::where('published', 1)
    ->selectRaw('type, COUNT(*) AS count')
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('type');

$qA = $types_count[1]->count;
$qP = $types_count[2]->count;
```